# Which javascript chart library can be used to implement a chart as given below

Tags: html, charts

I am using django to build the website, jQuery and ajax is used in the front end. I have been looking into d3.js and chart.js but these doesn't give the freedom to use those cliparts along the horizontal line. Can I achieve the same with any of the javascript libraries or is there something different?

[image: chart]

All suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Don't provide external links to any images or videos.

Comment: stackover flow only provide the option to link external videos. Sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.altocloud.com/blog/why-altocloud-uses-d3.js-for-data-visualization

This link has specified that altocloud uses d3.js for line drawing.Please   google it before asking in stackoverflow.